controller for ReorderableListView?
we know that ReorderableListView uses drag action by default to reorder items, is there any way to reorder it by code? Something like controller.reorder(oldIndex, newIndex)?

Flutter’s ReorderableListView does not provide a built-in method to reorder items programmatically, such as controller.reorder(oldIndex, newIndex). However, you can achieve this by manually updating the list and calling setState to reflect the changes.
Sample Example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Reorderable ListView')),
        body: ReorderableListExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReorderableListExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReorderableListExampleState createState() => _ReorderableListExampleState();
}

class _ReorderableListExampleState extends State<ReorderableListExample> {
  List<String> _items = List.generate(10, (index) => 'Item $index');

  void _reorderItems(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }
      final String item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
      _items.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  }

  void _reorderByCode(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    _reorderItems(oldIndex, newIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Example: Reorder the first item to the last position
            _reorderByCode(0, _items.length);
          },
          child: Text('Reorder First Item to Last'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ReorderableListView(
            onReorder: _reorderItems,
            children: _items
                .map((item) => ListTile(
                      key: ValueKey(item),
                      title: Text(item),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

I hope this may help you.
